# Excel, copy data in same column (Same worksheet), replacing blank lines, but not replacing next line with data

Tags: excel

This seems like it is very easy, but I have not written VBA in a few years.
The file I'm working with has set formats when I receive it.  I have to UnMerge columns (which works okay).
Then I need to Select range to be copied, Select copy range and then move the range up one line so I can paste data.
Can someone help with this last part?  I can't seem to get the move up, to select the correct range to select.

The paste is okay.

```
Sub unMerge()

    Range("A9:B5000").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.unMerge

End Sub

Sub CopyRange()

Dim R As Range

    Range("A10").Select
    Selection.copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCells = "R"
    ActiveCells = "R" - 1 'This is the line I really need help with.
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

Comment: I highly recommend [avoiding using `.Activate`/`.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  Instead, put the range into a variable, or work directly with the data.

Comment: Mainly focus on `ActiveCell`, this is the active cell. To keep your code as-is, but with the row-1, I believe you can do `ActiveCells.Offset(-1,0) = "R"`